# Error: A required parameter (username) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths

Tags: reactjs, next.js, directus

Nextjs, Directus and Algolia to build a drivers page where you can click on their profile and see their info. To see someones info the link would be http://localhost:3000/drivers/username - Nothing too fancy.
The issue I have is when I click a link I get **Error: A required parameter (username) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths**
The username *is* a string, so i don't understand it. Any direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
let config = {
  headers: {
    "authorization": 'Bearer xxx'
  }
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {

  const username = await fetch(`https://xxx.directus.app/users`,config).then(res => res.json());

  const paths = [username.data].map((driver) => ({
    params: {
      username: driver.username
    },
  }))

  return { paths, fallback: false }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {

  const results = await fetch(`https://xxx.directus.app/users/?fields=username&[username][_eq]=${params.username}`, config).then(res => res.json());
  return {
    props: {
      results
    },
  }
}

export default function Driver({ results }) {

  return (
    `<div>
      <h1>{results.data[0].username}</h1>
    </div>`
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely here `username.data` is already an `array` so you don't need to convert it to array otherwise you'll get this as `paths` : `[ { params: { username: undefined } } ]` since `[username.data]` contains only one element which is `username.data` and this latter does not have a `property` username because it is an array so the returned username will be `undefined`.

```
const paths = username.data.map((driver) => ({
  params: {
    username: driver.username
  },
}))
```

Comment: Ok thank you @AhmedSbai. The results object is just a is of usernames and nothing else. When i click on their link to their profile I guess the results should be their data, but its just returning the object

Comment: if it is a list of usernames then `username: driver` directly because `driver` is already the value if I understood well

Comment: Yeah so results is just the username for each user

 {
     username: ''
}